# Plot bars from different dataframes beside each other

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart

I´m about to analyze some data and stuck with the visualization and can´t get progress.

So, here are dummy dataframes which are similar to the ones I use:

```
df1<-data.frame(replicate(15,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))
df2<-data.frame(replicate(15,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))
df3<-data.frame(replicate(36,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))
df4<-data.frame(replicate(9,sample(0:200,1500,rep=TRUE)))
```

**So the first Problem**:

I wanna plot the bars from df1 and df2 besides each other. So that X1 from df2 is besides to X1 from df1 so that the change in the measurements are visible.
The aim is to count how often the observed values are over 120 for each station (x1,x2..,xn)

For df1 & df2:

```
barplot(colSums(df1[1:ncol(df1)]>120), las=2)
barplot(colSums(df1[1:ncol(df1)]>120), las=2)
```

this works as it should, and i get for each Dataframe the graphs I want. But how to put them together?
I tried the following:

```
test<-rbind(df1, df2)
barplot(colSums(test[1:ncol(test)]>120),beside=T, las=2)
```

But that doesn´t work, it just adds the observations >120 for each station.

Does anyone have a hint or something where I´m thinking in the wrong direction?

So i hope everything is understandable and if information is missing then just ask and i add it!

Thanks for your help in advance!

:)

Comment: It would be better if you could split up the two questions into separate threads.

Comment: can you ask 1 question?

Comment: @StupidWolf, i want to plot the bars of X1 from df1 and X1 from df2 (and xn following) beside each other, so that x1_df is directly beneath x1_df2. 
How i can do this?
As mentioned in the post above, under "The first problem", i tried something with rbind, but that doesnt work.

Comment: as i mentioned... it's better if you cut it down to 1 question. The barplot can be done. The boxplot is another question.

Comment: also i don't see how you can combine boxplots when there are different number of columns. as you can see.. this requires some detail. Please post that as another question. I can write something for the barplot

Comment: @StupidWolf, yeah i post the second question in a seperate post as soon as i can. And thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot your data long for ggplot2, and in this case for the barplot you can calculate the numbers first, and it helps to have proper names for your columns:

```
library(tidyr)

data_list = list(df1 = df1,df2 = df2,df3 = df3,df4 = df4)
tab_list = lapply(names(data_list),function(i){
               
              data.frame(data = i ,
                         n = colSums(data_list[[i]]>120),
                         station = 1:ncol(data_list[[i]])
                         )
             })

tab_list = do.call(rbind,tab_list)
```

Now we plot, this looks a bit crap because one of your data frames has 36 columns:

```
ggplot(tab_list,aes(x=factor(station),y=n,fill=data)) + 
geom_col(position="dodge")
```

[image]

You can also wrap it around with a facet:

```
ggplot(tab_list,aes(x=data,y=n,fill=data)) + 
geom_col(position="dodge") + facet_wrap(~station)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! That nearly solves my problem. Just a little thing, in my original dataframes there is a date column in the data frames as the first column, so this function needs to start at the second column, how do i properly implement that?

I tried: data.frame(data = i ,
             n = colSums(2:ncol(data_list[[i]]>120)),
             station = 2:ncol(data_list[[i]])
But this gives me an error
"Fehler in colSums(2:ncol(data_list[[i]] > 120)) : 
  'x' muss ein Array mit mindestens zwei Dimensionen sein "

Comment: and also this doesn´t work

tab_list = lapply(names(data_list),function(i){
  
  data.frame(data = i ,
             n = colSums(data_list[2:ncol([[i]])]>120),
             station = 2:ncol(data_list[[i]])
  )
})

Comment: ```'colSums(data_list[[i]][,-1])```

Comment: I tried this

`tab_list = lapply(names(data_list),function(i){
  
  data.frame(data = i ,
             n = colSums((data_list[[i]][,-1])>120),
             station = 1:ncol(data_list[[i]])
  )
})`

but get the following error:

 Fehler in data.frame(data = i, n = colSums((data_list[[i]][, -1]) > 120),  : 
  Argumente implizieren unterschiedliche Anzahl Zeilen: 1, 25, 26

Comment: ```station = 1:(ncol(data_list[[i]])-1)```

Comment: is there a way that i can put the heads from the dataframe on the x-axis. so that instead of 1,2,3,4...n, there is x1,x2,x3..xn?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question - if the data frames are all of equal row length, you could do sth. simple like:

```
boxplot(cbind(df1, df2, df3, df4))
```

But with 15 columns per data set you won't see anything anymore (60 columns next to each other).

[image]

Comment: no that´s not what i want. i want to have one box for the whole dataframe. so that in the plot are 4 boxes (one for each dataframe) beside each othe. so that i have one mean value for the whole dataframe and not for each xn.

Comment: Ah ok, but then you'd need to clarify first how to aggregate your X1-X15 columns. Would you like to pool all values together (i.e. all 1.5k *15 column) and boxplot this one new vector or would you like to aggregate each column first (e.g. calcualte the mean) and then do a boxplot for these 15 means in each data frame?

Comment: I would try both variants, cause i´m not yet sure which works the best for me in this project.